# 0 reputation loss?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

This is the third of fourth time I see this on my reputation page. I have a red 0 on yesterday's reputation gains:

[image]

I get this in both latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. I can't possibly think of any explanation for that, so it might be a bug, but I never know.

Comment: How many reputation were you expecting to lose yesterday?

Comment: Did you cast any downvotes on an answer that might have possibly been deleted? Just an idea. Does triggering a reputation recalculation fix it?

Comment: I did not perform any actions on SO yesterday. I barely browsed the front page questions for a few minutes then left. As for the downvotes cast, it's possible, but I don't have any way to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This most likely happens when someone accepts your answer and then unaccepts it on the same day. The net change is zero, but since the unaccept happened last, it colors it red.

Comment: Ahh. If it is indeed the case, then I think some kind of clarification should be given to it. That looks confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed as part of a [large refactor of the underlying reputation system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), these changes will be rolling out to the rest of network soon.